# Скрытие звездочками вводимых в поле ввода символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть поле ввода с логином и паролем. Вопрос в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы при вводе строки в поле пароля введённые данные "зазвёздовачились", но принимались программой в исходном виде?

[image: Оригинал:]

В какой вид хотелось бы привести:

[image: Как хотелось бы]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass

Comment: `widget = Entry(parent, show="•")`

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416486/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За скрытие вводимых символов в `Entry` отвечает параметр `show`:

```
widget = Entry(parent, show="*")
```

При получении данных из виджета все приходит так как вводил пользователь.